# iTunes play song via ScriptingBridge with queue

Tags: swift, itunes

When I use the `.playOnce` method, the iTunes "up next" queue is not updated.
`playOnce` seems to be the only method in `ScriptingBridge` to play a song.

I would like a method to do the same as double-clicking a song in iTunes: plays the song and add all songs after it to the queue, is it possible?

Comment: It's hard to know in which context this is. Which library are we talking about here?

Comment: I'm using `ScriptingBridge` to get info and control iTunes